# Check if all files mentioned in a list are there in input directory

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to create a validate function,
`def validate(path, name_list):` which will take a list of strings and a path. The `names_list` is a list of strings of expected file name prefixes. The file names may contain any arbitrary suffixes.

```py
my_names_list = ['daily', 'bills', 'costs', 'names', 'ids']
```

The directory may have files names like this:

```
Daily_tue.xlsx
BILLS_26.05.2023.xlsx
Costs.xlsx
```

The `validate` function should report for which file prefixes in the `my_name_list` no file name is found in the `path` directory.

For instance, with the above directory example, the output should be the following list:

```
Missing files: names, ids
```

Comment: What aspect of this task are you unable to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather simple, brute force solution that checks that a given prefix matches at least once any files name in the directory you are validating:

```py
import os

Name_list = ['daily', 'bills', 'costs', 'names', 'ids']


def validate(p, l):
    missing = set(l)
    f_names_in_path = os.listdir(p)

    for prefix in l:
        for f_name in f_names_in_path:
            if f_name.lower().startswith(prefix):
                missing.remove(prefix)
    return missing


print('Missing file prefixes: ', validate('path_to_your_files_to_test', Name_list))
```